# Print Integer in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, literals, octal

I have a simple program.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{
   int num = 000012345; printf("%d\n",num);
   return 0;
}
```

The above program gives 5349. Why ? I mean it should be wrong, but why 5349 ?

Comment: When you start a number with 0, you are using octal.

Comment: @ChrisD But (000012345)10 = (30071)8

Comment: @adrian008 No, the other way around: (12345)8 == 5349

Comment: @BaummitAugen yup (5349)10 = (12345)8. thx.

Comment: Don't mix `C` **and** `C++`. Stick to _either_ of them.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Its not a mix up. C++ has those things.

Comment: @adrian008 what "those things"? IIRC, it's _recommended_ to use `cout` in `C++` (Note: I'm a `C` person).

Comment: @SouravGhosh yes, i get your point. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisD No, he is using an editor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Numbers starting with `0` are octal in c/c++.

```
Octal  = 000012345
Decimal= 0×8⁸+0×8⁷+0×8⁶+0×8⁵+1×8⁴+2×8³+3×8²+4×8¹+5×8⁰ = 5349
Binary = 1010011100101
Hex    = 14E5
```

Answer (score 2):

A number starting with one or more leading zeros specifies octal format instead of decimal.  So 000012345 is 1 * 8^4 + 2 * 8^3 + 3 * 8^2 + 4 * 8^1 + 5 * 8^0 = 5349.

Similarly, a number starting with 0x is in hexadecimal format.